# How to preprocess typeahead.js json results before passing to templating (hogan.js)?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js, hogan.js

typeahead.js works nice when the results being returned will be an array:

```
  var simpleCountriesList = [
     "Andorra",
     "United Arab Emirates",
     "Afghanistan",
     "Antigua and Barbuda"
  ];
```

In my case, there is an array of objects but it is wrapped in an object like this:

```
  var countryObjectsWrappedInResults = {
   "results":[
      {
         "name":"Andorra"
      },
      {
         "name":"United Arab Emirates"
      },
      {
         "name":"Afghanistan"
      },
      {
         "name":"Antigua and Barbuda"
      }
   ]
};
```

or

```
{
   "maintainers":[
      {
         "name":"Jake Harding",
         "url":"https://twitter.com/JakeHarding"
      },
      {
         "name":"Tim Trueman",
         "url":"https://twitter.com/timtrueman"
      },
      {
         "name":"Veljko Skarich",
         "url":"https://twitter.com/vskarich"
      }
   ]
}
```

I created a small jsbin to illustrate the problem with both local and remote:
http://jsbin.com/OseWeKA/5/edit

I'm migrating from bootstrap typeahead where I was able to use updater to pop the array out of results.  What is the equivalent for twitter.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a 'filter:' to your remote dataset. Something like:

```
remote: {
    url: '...',
    filter: function (response) {
        retval = [];
        for (var i = 0;  i < response.maintainers.length;  i++) {
            retval.push(response.maintainers[i].name);
        }
        return retval;
    },
}
```

`filter` transforms your remote response into an array of datums.

Regardless, your fiddle doesn't work because your server does not support JSONP, where as you clearly specify `dataType: "jsonp"`. Your server also returns `text/plain` as the `Content-Type`, where as is should return a script. I assume there are not real issues in your "live" system.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan,  filter is the correct approach, but but I need to use a template and join multiple fields and my precompiled template seems to be failing.  I found the following example:var template = Hogan.compile("/%name%/", { delimiters: '/% %/' }), precompiled = function(context) { template.render(context); };   but something seems to be wrong.  Are you familiar with templates?  Do you know what it is missing?

Comment: By all means use a template, but you don't need to precompile it. Just pass a string such as '{{name}} -- {{other_field}}' or something along the lines. Regardless, the answer to your question is `filter:`.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest a hack for this .

```
  var newCountrylist = [];
 $.each( countryObjectsWrappedInResults.results , function(k , v ){
    newCountrylist.push(v.name);
  });
```

Comment: my jsbin example uses "local" but in my real app I'm actually using "remote" so I need to process the results that come back from the server.  Where do I process those results?

Comment: in the call back of the ajax request .. please post the code so i can get a better idea

Comment: I've updated the jsbin to include a 3rd example that uses "remote"

Comment: Alright then just make the Ajax request yourself , and apply my suggestion to it . And use the local method .